# VBA: tool using Vlookup in other file using path

Tags: excel, vba, path, vlookup

I'm trying to create a tool in which I can select 2 files. In the first file (File1 in range B2) a few changes are made before looking up values in the second file (File2 in range B3) and paste them in the first file. I've created two buttons in the tool to select the files.

I want to a write code to lookup values in the second file but I'm getting different errors retrieving the information from the second second file. Can anyone help me with this?

I need to paste the values in the 8th row from the second file in the first file (same column) using the lookup value from the first column.

See code below: this is what I tried. Debugging needed in the vlookup subsection. Can anyone help me with this? Is there an easier way to lookup the values?

```
Sub Past_dues_button12345()
'Macro to create past due list daily
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim File As String
Dim File2 As String

File = Sheets("Tool").Range("B2")
File2 = Sheets("Tool").Range("B3")

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(File)

remove_repair
add_columns_with_comments
add_data_new_column
vlookup
pastevalues
Sharewb

End Sub


Sub add_columns_with_comments()

    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column3]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PN"
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column2]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MRPc"
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comment"
    
End Sub

Sub vlookup()

    Dim rw As Long, x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Workbooks("Tool_SO.XLSM").Activate
    File2 = Sheets("Tool").Range("B3")
    
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(File2)
    
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Material Availability").Range("A1:H1000")

    With twb.Sheets("Material Availability")

        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.vlookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 8, False)
        Next rw

    End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not need **any selection/activation**. They only creates confusions and consumes Excel resources, without bringing any benefit. Then, what does "I'm getting different errors" mean? Are the `.Cells(rw, 1)` and first column of the  `x` range  **identic** formatted?

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple workbooks, I avoid *any* usage of `Application`level functions, where possible, and try to remove any aspect of going back and fourth between workbooks.

As such, arrays will be your friend.

---

Here is the very simple model I have constructed, in `Book1`:
[image]

Based on said model, I am hoping to `Match` with Column 1 and `Index` with Column 2, within `Book2` (`ThisWorkbook`).

There will be several items to dimension, including end rows/columns, the above array, the input terms, the output cells... but a good set-up carries the weight.

---

I will set this up in a single sub-routine for a single cell search term and output cell, noting that `InputBoxes` for workbook names, functions, etc., would make this more robust... **the goal of my post is to give an example.**

Here is the code I would generate to match within the above array (`searchArray` in my code), using a single cell for input/output:

```
Sub IndexFromExternalSearchSheetViaArray()
    'Using External Workbook
    Dim searchSheet As Worksheet
    Set searchSheet = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1)
    With searchSheet
        Dim searchSheetEndColumn As Long
        searchSheetEndColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Dim searchSheetEndRow As Long
        searchSheetEndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim searchArray As Variant
        searchArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(searchSheetEndRow, searchSheetEndColumn)).Value
    End With
    'Using This Workbook
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim searchTerm As Range
    Set searchTerm = outputSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Dim outputCell As Range
    Set outputCell = outputSheet.Cells(1, 2)
    'Matching/Indexing with Array
    Dim iterator As Long
    For iterator = 1 To searchSheetEndRow Step 1
        If searchTerm.Value = searchArray(iterator, 1) Then
            Dim outputValue As String
            outputValue = searchArray(iterator, 2)
            Exit For
        Else
            If iterator = searchSheetEndRow Then outputValue = "No match found"
        End If
    Next iterator
    'Final Output
    outputCell.Value = outputValue
End Sub
```

With a single input, after running the code, I may have:
[image]
or:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
two more questions with this:
I want to make the code read the path to the searchsheet (Book1 in your example) from a cell in the workbook from which I run the macro. How do I code this. I tried the following:

`File2 = Sheets("Tool").Range("B3") `
`Set searchSheet = Workbooks(File2).Worksheets(1)`

Also, as I just mentioned. I want to run the macro in a file (file1) that has the path of both File2 (the searchsheet) and File3 (the sheet in which the values are pasted. Can you explain that also?

Comment: @WillemMartens been a minute on this one... `searchSheet` and `outputSheet` both utilize `Workbook` names, so your File 2 and File3 names would be input... currently `outputSheet` uses `ThisWorkbook` and that would become a reference to `Workbooks("File3").Sheets(1)`, or whichever sheet is to be references.